# How to mock RxJs BehaviorSubject or Observables for testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rxjs, sinon

I've created a sample react hook which I want to test. The hooks imports an subject from another file and subscribe to it. On completion of that subject the internal state of the hook changes.

sampleBehaviourSubject.ts

```
export const subject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("I'm just an example")
```

useSample.js

```
const useSample(){

 const [state, setState] = useState("Nothing to show here")
 
 useEffect(()=>{

    subject.subscribe({
      complete: () => setState("The subject is completed")
    }) 

 },[])

 return [state]
}
```

I'm new to unit testing but I know that external dependencies can be mocked/stubbed using sinon.js . But I'm not able to figure out how can I mock an Observable/Subject and test this `useSample` hook. It'll be great if someone shows an example with **@testing-library/react-hooks**

Please note that this subject is subscribed at many other places hence I want to restore the mock/stub afterEach spec runs.

Comment: I do not think that "mocking" a basic library like rxjs makes too much sense

Comment: @Picci, so what could be the solution. Cause I want to unit test the `useSample` hook

Comment: Your unit test should actually import `rxjs` and `sampleBehaviourSubject.ts`, instanciate the React component, call `complete()` on `subject` and test that the state has changed. By the way, it sounds a bit strange to link a change of state to `complete`. Usually it should be linked to `next`, i.e. to the notifications of the subject. Since you are using rxjs with React, you may find interesting [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/reactive-programming-with-react-and-rxjs-88d2789e408a)